# Is there a Qt Dialog or Widget to interactively sort a string list?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I need to provide a reordering Dialog to let a user interactively order a list of strings. Does Qt already provide something fitting for this purpose?

I have searched the usual forums and examples but found nothing appropriate.

To clarify what I need:

### Raw List:

1. FileBaz
2. FileFoo
3. FileBar

### User sorted list

1. FileBar
2. FileFoo
3. FileBaz

So an arbitrary order as for example needed for merging formerly selected pdf files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt already supports it, there's nothing for you to do: *The standard views automatically support internal drag and drop, where items are moved around to change the order in which they are displayed.*

Further quoting the documentation:

- To enable item dragging, set the view's `dragEnabled` property to true.
- To allow the user to drop both internal or external items within the view, set the view's viewport()'s `acceptDrops` property to true.
- To show the user where the item currently being dragged will be placed if dropped, set the view's `showDropIndicator` property. This provides the user with continuously updating information about item placement within the view.
- To enable the user to move the items around within the view, we must set the list widget's dragDropMode to `QAbstractItemView::InternalMove`.

Below is a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that you can run to see it in action.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QListWidget w;
    w.addItem("Rosalind");
    w.addItem("Celia");
    w.addItem("Adam");
    w.addItem("Jaques");
    w.setDragEnabled(true);
    w.setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    w.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the solution. As you can see I used it as basis for my code

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. Something simple with a `Move up` button and a `Move down` button in coordination with a `QListWidget` may be useful, however. `Up` and `Down` would move around the list items in the respective direction, naturally.

Even easier, in my opinion, would be to use a `QTreeWidget`, as, if I recall correctly, there are some easy functions for swapping items around. A combination of something like

```
void insertTopLevelItem ( int index, QTreeWidgetItem * item )
QTreeWidgetItem *itemAbove ( const QTreeWidgetItem * item )
QTreeWidgetItem *itemBelow ( const QTreeWidgetItem * item ) 
QTreeWidgetItem *currentItem ()
int indexOfTopLevelItem ( QTreeWidgetItem * item )
```

may be useful. (Excerpts from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTreeWidget.html)

**Edit**: I haven't used `QListWidget` much, but seems fairly similar to the `QTreeWidget` in terms of ease of swapping items around. Either one works.

Comment: @Martin Do share if you get something working. I would be very interested in the resulting code.

Comment: Sure ! I just had a look at QListWidget, already looks promising

Comment: This does everything but answer the question :( If you don't know, you don't have to broadcast it... it's not really constructive. An answer should be an *answer*, not "well, I don't know, but here's what I just made up...".

Comment: @KubaOber This is not something I just *made up*. I researched functions that would be appropriate to my method of solving the problem (up and down buttons). I did not give the code outright, but gave a place for the original poster to start. Even after extensive reading of the Qt documentation I had yet to find what you posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake: 
Here is the solution I'm using in the end:

```
#include <QtGui>

class SortDialog:public QDialog{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    SortDialog(QStringList* pList, QString const& title,  QString const& middleButton);
    int getSelectedItem() const;

  private slots:
    void slotAccept();
    void slotItemUp();
    void slotItemDown();
    void slotSelectItem();

  private:
    QStringList* mpList;
    QListWidget* mpListWidget;
    int mSelectedItem;

};


SortDialog::SortDialog(QStringList* pList, QString const& title,  QString const& middleButton):
  QDialog(),
  mpList(pList),
  mpListWidget(new QListWidget()),
  mSelectedItem(-1){
  this->setWindowTitle(title);

  QHBoxLayout* pMainLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
  this->setLayout(pMainLayout);

  QVBoxLayout* pListLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  pMainLayout->addLayout(pListLayout);

  pListLayout->addWidget(mpListWidget);
  mpListWidget->setDragEnabled(true);
  mpListWidget->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
  mpListWidget->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);

  boostForeach(QString const& string, *mpList) {
    mpListWidget->addItem(string);
  }
  mpListWidget->setMinimumWidth(mpListWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0)+10);
  mpListWidget->adjustSize();

  mpList->clear();

  QPushButton* confirm = new QPushButton(tr("Confirm"));
  connect(confirm, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotAccept()));
  pListLayout->addWidget(confirm);
  confirm->setDefault(true);

  QVBoxLayout* pUpDownLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  pMainLayout->addLayout(pUpDownLayout);

  QPushButton* up = new QPushButton(tr("Up"));
  connect(up, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotItemUp()));
  pUpDownLayout->addWidget(up);

  QPushButton* down = new QPushButton(tr("Down"));
  connect(down, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotItemDown()));
  pUpDownLayout->addWidget(down);

  QPushButton* ground = new QPushButton(middleButton);
  connect(ground, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSelectItem()));
  pUpDownLayout->addWidget(ground);

  this->adjustSize();
}

int SortDialog::getSelectedItem() const{
  return mSelectedItem;
}


void SortDialog::slotAccept(){
  int count = mpListWidget->count();
  for(int index = 0; index < count; index++){
    QListWidgetItem * item = mpListWidget->item(index);
    mpList->push_back(item->text());
  }

  this->close();
}

void SortDialog::slotItemUp(){
  int row = mpListWidget->currentRow();
  if(row>0){
    QListWidgetItem* pTemp = mpListWidget->takeItem(row);
    mpListWidget->insertItem(row-1,pTemp);
    mpListWidget->setCurrentRow(row-1);
  }
}

void SortDialog::slotItemDown(){
  int row = mpListWidget->currentRow();
  if(row<mpListWidget->count()-1){
    QListWidgetItem* pTemp = mpListWidget->takeItem(row);
    mpListWidget->insertItem(row+1,pTemp);
    mpListWidget->setCurrentRow(row+1);
  }
}

void SortDialog::slotSelectItem(){
  int count = mpListWidget->count();
  for(int index = 0; index < count; index++){
    QListWidgetItem * item = mpListWidget->item(index);
    QFont font = item->font();
    font.setBold(false);
    item->setFont(font);
  }

  mSelectedItem =mpListWidget->currentRow();
  qDebug() << mSelectedItem;
  QListWidgetItem* pTemp = mpListWidget->currentItem();
  QFont font = pTemp->font();
  font.setBold(true);
  pTemp->setFont(font);
}
```