# What is the right way to keep a QtTableWidget and a list in sync, in PySide?

Tags: qt, pyside, qtablewidget

I have a simple list:
`mylist = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

and a QtTableWidget with 1 column. I would like to keep the data in mylist in sync with that in the QtTableWidget, including allowing drag-and-drop reordering (i.e., the user can do that, and `mylist` gets updated) and programmatic changes (i.e., I update `mylist` and the table gets updated).

What is the *right* way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in general there's no way in Qt/C++ proper to link a generic data structure with a view. Models are such instrumented data structures that allow trivial linking with views -- generic lists, like say `QStringList` can't be used like that.

In Python it should be possible to inject attributes into an existing instance of any list to turn it into a model that notifies its views of changes done to it. I don't know if any Qt-to-Python bridges do that sort of a thing, I can only give C++ perspective on this. Someone who knows PyQt or PySide is welcome to chime in and edit as appropriate.

Use a [`QStringListModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html) for the model. Enable drag-drop reordering on the view as follows:

```
view.setDragEnabled(true);
view.setDropIndicatorShown(true);
view.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237916/1329652) has a full example that uses the convenience widget [`QListWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) with its buit-in model. That may be better as a starting point, and for lists that can be reasonably manipulated with a mouse, it's a good choice. Generally if a model has 100s of items, it can't be readily manipulated with just a mouse without a way of doing real-time finds or pruning of some sort -- scrolling so many items is a usability nightmare. So don't do it.

Qt's documentation would be a good plate to start learning. Read about the [model/view framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html). Then look at [`QStringListModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html) and your chosen view, say [`QTableView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html) or [`QListView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html).

Comment: Can you be a littttle bit more explicit on the model thing? I'm very new to this. Alternatively, a link to a good tutorial would be great.